# Channel entries entry_id parameter issue

Tags: entries

EE2.8

If I reorder the IDs in the following entries tag the output order remains the same, why?

```
{exp:channel:entries
  entry_id="2680|396|"
}
  <p>{title}</p>
  <p>{entry_id}</p>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I can only get the order to change if one of the IDs are changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fixed_order="3|5|10"